# Upload image with CK Editor gives undefined method 'size' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I have created a rails app using

```
gem 'ckeditor'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
```

Everything works fine. But when I try to upload an image in local server, it is not uploading and an error is created in rails server

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass):
  mini_magick (3.7.0) lib/mini_magick.rb:24:in `choose_processor'
  mini_magick (3.7.0) lib/mini_magick.rb:64:in `mogrify?'
  mini_magick (3.7.0) lib/mini_magick/image.rb:360:in `run_command'
  mini_magick (3.7.0) lib/mini_magick/image.rb:203:in `[]'
  ckeditor (4.0.10) lib/ckeditor/backend/carrierwave.rb:57:in `read_dimensions'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:85:in `block in process!'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81:in `each'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81:in `process!'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:122:in `cache!'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:327:in `cache'
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:179:in `data='
  carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:38:in `data='
  ckeditor (4.0.10) app/controllers/ckeditor/application_controller.rb:13:in `respond_with_asset'
  ckeditor (4.0.10) app/controllers/ckeditor/pictures_controller.rb:12:in `create'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:433:in `_run__908729428__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__448849553__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/shivakumaarmgs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/shivakumaarmgs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/shivakumaarmgs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

I have the following `mini_magick` and `carrierwave` gems installed

```
/home/shivakumaarmgs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/mini_magick-3.7.0
/home/shivakumaarmgs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0
```

What is the problem? Someone help..!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have also faced the same issue.

The problem is solved after I installed imagemagick

sudo apt-get install imagemagick